# Display comment form without the comment thread

Tags: 8, comments

What are some ways of rendering a comment form without also displaying the comments?

What about creating a block contains the form?  If that's possible, what are some links to documentation touching on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display comment form without comments list, you need to override [`field--comment.html.twig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21classy%21templates%21field%21field--comment.html.twig/8.2.x) template, and remove the following lines:

```
  {% if comments and not label_hidden %}
    {{ title_prefix }}
    <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</h2>
    {{ title_suffix }}
  {% endif %}

  {{ comments }}
```

to override it:

1. From your theme, just create one of the following twig file in you templates folder, and put in it `field--comment.html.twig` content without the above section.

```
   * field--node--comment--article.html.twig
   * field--node--comment.html.twig
   * field--node--article.html.twig
   x field--comment.html.twig
   x field--comment.html.twig
   * field.html.twig
```

Note: the above suggestions for article content type, you may have different suggestions.

2. From your module, implement [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/8.9.x) for one of the suggestions like the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function MODULENAME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'field__node__comment__article' => [
      'base hook' => 'field'
    ],
  ];
}
```

And make your changes in `MODULENAME/templates/field--node--comment--article.html.twig`

Comment: Thanks, @berramou!  This worked after I changed "hook" to "base hook" in `hook_theme()`.

Comment: welcome, glad that helped  